# Using ld to partially link archives

Tags: linker, ld, partial

I'm trying to link several libraries / archives (generated using ar) together to produce an intermediate .o file, however I'm a bit confused with the syntax and the man page didn't really help..

If I understand everything correctly, I need to use this command:

```
ld -r -o output.o -Lsearchdir -larchivename
```

With search dir being the directory my libraries are in, and archivename being the archives without the lib prefix or the .a suffix.

Comment: The linker complains about some undefined references, I just wanted to double check I was calling it with the right options / syntax.

Answer (score 0):

If you link C++, the docs for -r switch mention something special needed for C++ constructors:

*When linking C++ programs, this option will not resolve references to constructors; to do that, use `-Ur'*

http://www.math.utah.edu/docs/info/ld_2.html